# Search a string in a directory

Tags: python, string, directory, subdirectory

Hi i wrote this code for searching a keyword in a list of files

```
import glob
import os
print "enter directory path"
path=raw_input()
print "Enter keyword"
key=raw_input()
os.chdir(path)
for files in glob.glob("*.*"):
    with open(file) as f:
         contents=f.read()
    if key in contents:
          print file
```

I am relatively new to Python.Can anyone please help me to modify the same for searching in sub directory too??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(your_dir_path):
    for file in files:
        file = os.path.join(root, file)    
        with open(file) as f:
             ...
```

Comment: I tried this one but it shows an error like this Traceback (most recent call last): File "s.py", line 10, in <module> with open(file) as fdf: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'accounts.cfg'

Comment: if you are using linux, it's much faster to call `grep` using `subprocess` module

Comment: I dont know how to use that.I'm just a beginner